# How to use MASM for assembly language on Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, assembler

How can I run the code of Masm on Ubuntu? I cannot use Windows as a virtual machine and neither can I use Nasm.

Comment: Alternatively you could also try an online compiler if this is just for educational purposes. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627051/test-masm-programs-online).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using DOSBox with [this guide](https://ksaikiranr.wordpress.com/2016/05/01/run-masm-programs-on-ubuntu/). These instructions will run in all versions of Ubuntu.

1. Download the all files in the masm folder from [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1DiPkxLHBZHTWVQVVNlYVptU3M&usp=sharing).
2. Install dosbox with the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt install dosbox
   ```

#### Usage

1. Write an masm program (e.g. myProgram) in any text editor and save it.
2. Mount the location where the downloaded folder is available (e.g. `~/Downloads`). To mount, launch dosbox and run this command in dosbox:

   ```
   mount c: ~/Downloads/masm
   ```
3. Change the current working directory to c.

   ```
   c:
   ```
4. Assemble the code.

   ```
   masm myProgram;
   ```
5. Link the file.

   ```
   link myProgram;
   ```
6. Run the executable.

   ```
   debug myProgram.exe
   ```
7. Type `-g` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
8. Once the output is displayed, enter `q` to quit.

Comment: I tried the above one but while linking it is showing **Fatal Error L1903:obj not found** ..

Comment: And if i am trying to include `INCLUDE IRVINE32.inc` then it is showing me error **not found**   @karael , @Saxtheowl

Answer (score 0):

To use masm from your terminal, an easy way is with dosemu

```
sudo apt install dosemu
```

cd to where your MASM.EXE is located and execute

```
dosemu MASM.EXE <code.asm>
```

I've tried it with MASM 5.1, works perfectly.

Hope I have helped :)